# The Legendre-Fenchel transform of $BV$ semi-norm

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am reading a numerical paper in which it calls some "easy" facts from convex analysis but I can't justify it...

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^2$ be open. Define for a function $u\in L^1(\Omega)$ and
$$
J[u]=\sup\left\{\int_\Omega u(x)\text{ div }\xi(x)\,dx:\,\xi\in C_c^1(\Omega;\,\mathbb R^2),\,|\xi(x)|\leq 1\right\}
$$
which is the standard $TV$ semi-norm.

Then it claims that the Legendre-Fenchel transform
$$
J^*(v)=\sup_u\left<u,v\right>_X-J[u]
$$
is the characteristic function of a closed convex set $K$ where $K$ is the closure of the set 
$$
\{\text{div }\xi:\xi\in C_c^1(\Omega;\mathbb R^2),|\xi(x)|\leq 1\text{ for all }x\in\Omega\}\tag 1
$$
and we can recover
$$
J[u]=\sup_{v\in K}\left<u,v\right>_X.\tag 2
$$
(I looked carefully over the paper, they never define what is $X$...So I guess it is the dual pair?)

The paper refers to book [Ekeland and Temama](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0898714508). I know it is a classical book but it is hard to find where this statement is... Could anybody just explain to me how $(1)$ and $(2)$ be verified?

Thank you!

Comment: A basic fact to be aware of is that (at least in a finite dimensional setting) the convex conjugate of a norm is the indicator function of the dual norm unit ball.  Also, the conjugate of the conjugate is the original function (under mild assumptions), which helps to explain equation (2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not specific to total variation; this is how the Legendre-Fenchel transform works for norms. Here one should really think of the space of $C^1_c$ vector fields as the original space, $X$. It is given the supremum norm. The $L^1$ functions induce linear functionals on this space via 
$$
\langle u,\xi\rangle = \int_\Omega u(x)\text{ div }\xi(x)\,dx
$$
and the BV seminorm is just the dual norm (some functions end up being zero functionals).

Let $X$ be any vector space with norm $\|\cdot\|$. For $v\in X^*$, the quantity 
$$J^*(v) = \sup_u (\left<u,v\right>-\|u\|)$$
can only attain the values  $0$ and $\infty$. Indeed, $J^*(v)\ge 0$ because $u=0$ is a choice. And if some value of $u$ gives a positive amount, then scaling it yields $J(v)=\infty$.

More specifically, $J^*(v)=0$ iff $\left<u,v\right> \le 1$ for all vectors $u$ with $\|u\|\le 1$. This is exactly the definition of the unit ball for the dual norm. Conversely, 
$$\|u\|= \sup_v (\left<u,v\right>-J^*(v))$$
because the right hand side is simply the supremum taken over $v$ with dual norm at most $1$.